# Bind DateTimePicker to UTC, but display and manipulate in local time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DateTimePicker in Windows Forms that I wish to bind to a UTC DateTime value. But even though I use DateTime.SpecifyKind() to make sure the value Kind is set to UTC, the DateTimePicker control does not display the value in Local time. Is there a way to present the local time to the user and allow them to manipulate the value in their local time, while the binded value remains in UTC?

Comment: Please show us the code first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.format?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and [`Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.parse?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of the [`Binding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) object.

So, assuming you have universal time in data source:

- To show the local time in `DateTimePicker`, you should handle `Format` event of the binding and convert the value to local time using [`ToLocalTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method of `DateTime`
- To put the universal time back to the data source, you should handle `Parse` event of the binding and convert the local time which is coming from `DateTimePicker` back to universal time using [`ToUniversalTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8)

You can learn more about those events in docs:

- [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.format?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8): Occurs when the property of a control is bound to a data value.
- [`Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.parse?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8): Occurs when the value of a data-bound control changes.

**Example**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(DateTime));

    dateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add("Value", dt, "Column1");
    dateTimePicker1.DataBindings["Value"].Format += 
        (s, a) => a.Value = ((DateTime)a.Value).ToLocalTime();
    dateTimePicker1.DataBindings["Value"].Parse += 
        (s, a) => a.Value = ((DateTime)a.Value).ToUniversalTime();

    dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0));
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0]["Column1"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Intercepting the binding process was just what I needed - thanks!