# If else Statement to display text rather than double

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to render a string rather than a double value.

I have a method which produces random Voltage. This method is passed as Parameter to further calculate Pressure. I am trying to write the code so if the (random) Voltage is <= 2 OR >= 10, the associated textbox should read "Off". The textbox now reads Pressure value using method AveragePressure. Please find the code with the question. Thank you in advance.

Views/DiagnosticsView.cs:

```
    private void PresBindings()
    {


    private void PresBindings(Control c, string propertyName, object dataSource, string dataMember)
    {
        c.DataBindings.Add(propertyName, dataSource, dataMember, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.PropertyChanged);
    }

        Binding(textBoxVoltage, "Text", viewModel.Gas, nameof(PressureViewModel.Voltage)); //Voltage method in SystemMonitorViewModel.cs
```

Model/Firmware.cs:

```
    public double GetVoltage()
    {
        double randVoltage;
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            randVoltage = r.NextDouble()*8.0;
            return randVoltage;

        }
    }
```

Monitor.cs
        string p = "-";

```
   public string Pressure
    {
        get
        {
            return p;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!string.Equals(value, p))
            {
                p = value;
                Property();
            }
        }
    }
```

Model/Gauge.cs:

```
    protected Average averagePressure;
    public double AveragePressure
    {
        get
        {
            GetAverage();
        }
    }

    public override void Read(double voltage, bool trip)
    {
        double P;
        Voltage = voltage;
        this.trip= trip;

        if ((voltage <= 2 || voltage >= 10))
        {
               ???
        }

    }
```

View/MainViewModel.cs

```
        Monitor.Gas.Pressure = sys.VacuumSystem.Gas.AveragePressure.ToString("0.0E-0");
        Monitor.Gas.Voltage = sys.VacuumSystem.Gas.Voltage.ToString("0.00");
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to by "textbox," and your code example contains no code that renders anything.  The only cshtml you have included merely calls a method that returns void. Can you please clarify what you are trying to change here?

Comment: First, `Random r = new Random();` declare this outside of your `GetVoltage`, create it one time in the class so you can re-use it. Secondly, where's this `TextBox` at, also are you doing any binding?

Comment: Hi thank you for your prompt reply. I have updated the question with Binding code at the top.

Comment: You can use [`control.DataBindings.Add([Binding])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlbindingscollection), with a Binding object. Then use the `Binding.Format()` and `Binding.Parse()` events to convert it both ways. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58654528/7444103), posted the other day.

Comment: Right. thank you. I will have a read through now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the data in your binding.
This `control.DataBindings.Add(propertyName, dataSource, dataMember, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);` should become this

```
Binding binding = new Binding(propertyName, dataSource, dataMember, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
binding.Format+= (sender, e) => 
{
    if(double.Parse(e.Value.ToString()) <= 2 || double.Parse(e.Value.ToString()) >= 10)
        e.Value = "Off";
};
control.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

Comment: Hi Groger Thanks for coming back to me. If I now have Voltage below/equal to 2 or more than/equal to 10 , Value of Pressure still renders and does not print "Off" in textBoxGasGunVoltage. Is there anything I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by writing a boolean getter and setter method:

```
    public bool On
    {
        get; set;
    } = false;

    public override void Read(double voltage, bool trip)
    {
        double P;
        Voltage = voltage;
        this.trip= trip;

        if ((voltage <= 2 || voltage >= 10))
        {
               On = false;
        }
        else 
        {
               On = true;
        }....

   public string getText()
    {
        if (On)
            return AveragePressure.ToString("0.0E-0");
        else
            return "Off";
    }
```

View/MainViewModel.cs

```
    ViewModelLocator.Monitor.Gas.Pressure = VacuumSystem.Gas.getText();
```

Thank you guys for your help!!!